# Background check a Box in the Vagrant Box Catalog

Tags: centos, fedora, vagrant

Looking through the [Vagrant Box Catalog](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search) I am wondering how one can obtain more information about certain available 'boxes' (images).

There are profile pages, but often they are very sparse.

Examples:

- [generic/fedora27](https://app.vagrantup.com/generic/boxes/fedora27) - who is behind the 'generic' user profile? HashiCorp?
- [centos/7](https://app.vagrantup.com/centos/boxes/7) - profile is incomplete; at least each release text links to the official CentOS Blog such that one can verify that CentOS is behind this box

In general, I also want to have a look at the playbook source that was used to generate a specific Vagrant box image. Is there a generic way to look it up?

Comment: There is a related post  [Who creates the "generic" Vagrant boxes?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/99OzkAJ5OgA) on the Vagrant mailinglist (2017-11). The thread doesn't answer the posted question and the replies by the HashiCorp support guy are of the neither-confirm-nor-deny type.

Answer (score 1):

HashiCorp image storage platform requires to provide only email address to store images, check it yourself: https://app.vagrantup.com/account/new

During image uploading process you may provide MarkDown text information optionally.

You should audit images before using it. If you can't find appropriate information - don't use image.

You can upload your own image to https://app.vagrantup.com and use them as:

```
vagrant add $REGISTRATION_USER_NAME/$IMAGE_NAME
```

There is `config.vm.box_download_checksum` and `config.vm.box_download_checksum_type` so you can ensure that no one tampers images.

Also you can provide direct link to your image hosted elsewhere:

```
vagrant add http://mycorp.com/vbox/alpine.box
```